# Extract a value out of html using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Im new to c# and htmlagilitypack and i been trying to get the value of signup_form_id
which is 2079787163

```html
<form name="setupform" id="setupform" method="post" action="/signup/" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="blog" />
<input type="hidden" name="stage" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="signup" />
<input type='hidden' name='signup_form_id' value='2079787163' /><input type="hidden" id="_signup_form" name="_signup_form" value="9783b65654" />
```

Heres my coding

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("https://signup.wordpress.com/signup/");
var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@name='signup_form_id'");
Console.WriteLine(value.InnerText);
```

I know something is really wrong with my xpath expression and im really clueless about this. Can any kind soul give some suggestions? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your code fails on the `doc.Load` line, because that 'Load' method does not support a URI, only a file path. You should use `HtmlWeb`'s `Load` method to download the HTML.

Second, the flaws in your XPath:

- you forgot a closing bracket `]`
- there is no form with the name set to `signup_form_id`

In conclusion, you should modify your code as follows:

```
var url = "http://signup.wordpress.com/signup/";

var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = htmlWeb.Load(url);

var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@id='setupform']");
Console.WriteLine(value.OuterHtml);
```

---

Update: It's good that you've clarified the question; I had a wrong understanding of the problem initially.

It looks like you're looking for an `input` tag, not the `form`. So, your XPath should be modified to match this requirement.

Here's the code that reads the piece of data you need:

```
var url = "http://signup.wordpress.com/signup/";

var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = htmlWeb.Load(url);

var signupFormIdElement = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='signup_form_id']");

var signupFormId = signupFormIdElement.GetAttributeValue("value", "");

Console.WriteLine(signupFormId);
```

Comment: I think the xpath expression you are after would be something like `//input[@name='signup_form_id']/@value` or perhaps the more strict `//form[@id='setupform']/input[@name='signup_form_id']/@value`.

Comment: thanks w0lf and @rmhartog for ur feedbacks. Yes im trying to get just the value of 2079787163 . Using //input[@name='signup_form_id']/@value gets me till "<input type='hidden' name='signup_form_id' value='75509619'>" . Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use that xpath in combination with InnerHTML, instead of OuterHTML? I have no way of trying that, but HTH.

Comment: @rmhartog Nah, tried it doesnt work. Didnt give me any results at all. Thanks for the effort man! i try to find out more on parsing the results using the normal way.

Comment: I have same proble. Seems like //input[@name='signup_form_id']/@value not working on hidden types. any Idea?